# React Add/Remove and Toggle Class of Sidebar with background overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

Here my code: http://codepen.io/rafaelfndev/pen/gmqmvo

I need to add class:

`.overflow` to `body`

`.overlay-active` to `.overlay`

`.sidebar-active` to `#sidebar`

I need add when I click on `.show-sidebar` independent of the location of the component that has this classes. If I click on `.hide-sidebar`, I need remove this classes, and if I click on `.toggle-class` I need to toggle this classes...

I know how to do this with jQuery, but I read somewhere that is wrong manipulate React elements with jQuery...

I need to do exactly what this code does, but without jQuery, just using the React pattern:

```
$('.toggle-sidebar').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('sidebar-active');
    $('body').toggleClass('overflow');
    $('overlay').toggleClass('overlay-active');
});

$('.show-sidebar').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar').addClass('sidebar-active');
    $('body').addClass('overflow');
    $('overlay').addClass('overlay-active');
});

$('.hide-sidebar, overlay').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar').removeClass('sidebar-active');
    $('body').removeClass('overflow');
    $('overlay').removeClass('overlay-active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly which elements you are using for sidebar, but I will consider it as a div and the others as buttons.

You can keep a state on the main component(The component controlling the sidebar and the buttons) and change the state with the onClick of each button. With this state you can set some styles on you sidebar or activate classes with something like [classenames lib](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)

I made this [codepen](http://codepen.io/jhas/pen/BWMRLM) showing how you can follow this approach, hope it help you. It is basically a SideBar component receiving a props called "show" and using it do change a div style. The App component has a "show" state that changes with the click on the buttons and passes it to SideBar component.

The code is as follow:

```
class SideBar extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return <div style={{display: this.props.show?'block':'none'}}>
      I am a side bar!
    </div>
  }; 
}

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {show: true};
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
      <SideBar show={this.state.show}/>
      <button onClick={()=>this.setState({show: !this.state.show})} >toggle</button>
      <button onClick={()=>this.setState({show:true})} >add</button>
      <button onClick={()=>this.setState({show:false})}>remove</button>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this code updates only to certain component, I need to update to component that is not a child or parent, and also another component that is not connected with them, something like all listening to an event, and changing *all* (class) at the same time ...

Comment: So use component composition. Simply have a container component contain other components that have to change their state depending on click event, and pass that state via props. If you see this pattern coming up frequently, it may be a good idea to use state management library such as mobx or redux to dispatch events, that modify global state, and have your components bind to that global state.